# How to package a runnable jar with libs and configuration

Tags: java, maven, package, dependency-management

I'd like to package my project as zip with following structure

```
/myapp
MyApplication.jar
/lib
  -log4j.jar
  -struts.jar
/conf
  -beans.xml
  -app.xml
```

I run `mvn clean package` and `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and copy manually, I don't know how to do that with maven command

Comment: Lib part is easy with onejar-maven-plugin (http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/). Not sure if it can handle the conf, maybe through "binLib" configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Assembly plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/